# Button text transition with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, transition

I have a fade in function made with pure javascript as this [site](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) shows.

```
function fadeIn(el) {
  var opacity = 0;

  el.style.opacity = 0;
  el.style.filter = '';

  var last = +new Date();
  var tick = function() {
    opacity += (new Date() - last) / 400;
    el.style.opacity = opacity;
    el.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + (100 * opacity)|0 + ')';

    last = +new Date();

    if (opacity < 1) {
      (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || setTimeout(tick, 16);
    }
  };

  tick();
}
```

What I need is to apply this transition in a change of button text, something like:

```
var firstChild = document.getElementById('my-button').firstChild;
firstChild.data = 'Another text';
fadeIn(firstChild);
```

Of course this do not works as expected, but I wanted something to achieve a behavior that on a change text, a fade in transition is triggered only to the text, not to the entire button.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You've got the code right there, what's not working?

Comment: Actually I want to change the text with a fade in transition and don't know how to. I'm updating my ask now.

Comment: Check my answer, if it works, you could accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using firstChild i assume your text is inside a child element of the button element, if that is the case, this will work.

Click the blue "run code snippet" button at the bottom to see it in action.

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){fadeOut(this.firstChild, newText)});

var newText = "World!";

function fadeOut(e, nT) {
 o=1; 
 t=setInterval(function () {
  if(o <= 0.1){
   clearInterval(t);
   e.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=0)";
    if(nT != undefined) {
     e.innerHTML = nT;
     fadeIn(e);
    }  
 }
  e.style.opacity = o;
  e.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity='+o*100+")";
  o-=o*0.05;
 }, 10);
}

function fadeIn(e) {
 o=0; 
 t=setInterval(function () {
  if(o >= 0.9){
   clearInterval(t);
   e.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=1)";
  }
   e.style.opacity = o;
   e.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity='+o*100+")";
   o+=0.05;
 }, 25);
}
```

```css
#btn {
  color: Black;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn"><p>hello</p></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the text colour, using this function, you can set it's colour using RGBA - the A stands for the alpha channel.

So, something like this:

```
el.style.color = "rgba(0,0,0, "+ OPACITY +")" // Opacity is 0 - 1
```

You could also make your code more modular, allowing you to edit any style property with this fade function.

```
function fadeIn(el,prop,color) {
  var opacity = 0;

  el.style[prop] = 0;

  var last = +new Date();
  var tick = function() {
    opacity += (new Date() - last) / 400;
    el.style[prop] = "rgba("+color+","+opacity+")";

    last = +new Date();

    if (opacity < 1) {
      (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || setTimeout(tick, 16);
    }
  };

  tick();
}
```

now you could do both:

```
fadeIn(firstChild,"background", "255,0,0"); // fade in background to red
fadeIn(firstChild,"color", "0,0,0"); // fade in text to black
```